# ClassCastException while sorting an array using Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I have like this class to compare Y Cordinates (descending order)
and I have predefined Point class .

In main class ,I am sending Compare Y array which is keeping points(type =Point) `Arrays.sort(array);` and it gives me `ClassCastExeption` ,

how can ı fix this problem.

---

```
public class CompareY  implements Comparator<Point> {

public CompareY(){
}

@Override
public int compare(Point a1, Point a2) {

    if (a1.y > a2.y)
        return -1;
    else if (a1.y < a2.y)
        return 1;
    else {
        if (a1.x < a2.x)
            return 1;
        else if (a1.x > a2.x)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you point out where you get an error..?

Comment: and show us how you use your construct. btw you can achieve line breacks in questions by adding to whitespaces at the end of each line

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the error. Looks like you are trying to sort an `Object` array that contains objects of different types.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are int, you can use `return a1.y - a2.y` to avoid verbosity, if not, then `Math.signum()` will help.

Comment: @serdar See my answer for an explanation on why you get a `ClassCastException` and how to fix this. I think the question that you have posted is complete and no additional code needs to be posted from your end to narrow down the issue. +1

Comment: Make sure every element in the array is a Point, and make sure you're importing the correct Point in your comparator.

Comment: @serdar Since Java 8, you can simply use `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.y).thenComparingInt(p -> p.x)` as comparator instead of your `CompareY`.

Comment: @isnot2bad Or if one does not have Java-8, they can use `method-local-anonymous-inner-classes`. ;). That being said, I like the idea of being able to compare objects in Java 8 without the need to explicitly implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` using the methods you have shown.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Arrays.sort(Object[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) method expects a type that implements `Comparable`. If you are creating an array of `CompareY` objects, you should note that `CompareY` does not implement `Comparabe` and therefore, you get a `ClassCastException` at runtime since `CompareY` cannot be cast to a `Comparable`. Similarly, if you are creating an `array` of `Point` objects, you will still get a `ClassCastException` since `Points` does not implement `Comparable`

To fix the issue :

1. Create an `array` of `Point` objects.
2. Use the [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) method that takes a `Comparator`.

Example :

```
Point[] points = new Point[]{new Point(..),new Point(...)};
Arrays.sort(points,new CompareY());
```

Alternately, you can have the `Point` class implement `Comparable` and define the natural ordering for `Points`. You can then use the `Array.sort(Object[] a)` method directly.

Comment: ı already implement comparable interface in point class and it is work properly.ı used Array.sort(points,new CompareY()); it works .thank you for answer.

Comment: @serdarözer I am posting this as part of the question. Are you still getting a `ClassCastException` after implementing `Comparable`? Can you edit your question with the code that creates the `array` and passes it to the `Arrays.sort` method please?

Comment: @serdarözer So you are saying that you are facing the issue even after implementing `Comparable`? I don't think that's possible. That being said, I believe my answer pointed (pun intended) you in the right direction so don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: no just write after  this piece of code  Array.sort(points,new CompareY()); and ı accepted answer but ı dont have enough reputation for upvote :-)

Comment: @serdarözer My bad. I keep forgetting the restriction on upvotes until a certain rep is reached ;)